# Combine rows from two datasets if the have an identical time, python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, find, element

I have two datasets, one array called "chekan" size(86352,6) and a dataframe called "nav_reduceed_df" size(260757,10). As you can see in the figure I have timestamps for my data. I would like to find all the rows that have identical time, and put it  in an output array/dataframe. From the time and date I have calculated the decimal day of year (doy) for both datasets, it is column 6 in the cehkan array, and column 10 (deciJday) in the dataframe. (Please note that the figure does not display all the decimals). [image: Overview of the two datasets].

If  the same time is found in both datasets, I need it to give me the output with (row time(doy),row value from column 4 in chekan-array, row lat from nav_reduceed_df,row lon from nav_reduceed_df)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me convert the numpy array to dataframe first..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_newdata=pd.DataFrame(data=chekan,columns=['d','h','m','s','a','decimal_day'])
df_merge=pd.merge(left_on='decimal_day',right_on='deciJday',how='inner')
df_merge[[give all the columns that you want here]]
```